# haskell repl getting the type of nested functions

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghci

I'm just asking if you can see the type of nested functions using the repl in haskell?

When using a language server, you can easily see the type of a nested function such as:

```
foo = bar where 
  bar = id
```

of course, you get:

```
bar :: a -> a
defined in ....
```

I assume that this should be possible in the repl but, I haven't yet found a way to do this.

```
ghci> let foo = bar where bar = id
ghci> :t bar

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: bar
```

(which makes sense since it's not a top level function)

Comment: I don’t know if there’s a direct way to do this. But maybe it’d be helpful to know that, if you set a breakpoint in `foo` then you can ask for `:type bar` there; and you can set a breakpoint on a nested definition like `foo.bar` as well.